# Nft randomness using baseURI

Tags: solidity, ipfs, nft

How I understand if we use baseURI where CID is a folder hash there is 2 ways:
1.Set baseURI before the sale started means people know what nft they will get
2.Set baseURI after the sale is finished means people do not know what nft they will get but it will be impossible to find out what kind of nft they received immediately after minting

Are there any other options?